# Create a Windows shortcut on Unix

Tags: windows, unix, shortcut

I'm looking for a tool that will allow me to create Windows shortcuts on a Unix (BSD) machine.
Can anyone point me to one?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: To clarify, you want to create a native [Windows .LNK file](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd871305.aspx) on a BSD machine?

Comment: @jscott Precisely

Answer (score 0):

Here is another disscussion on subject on SF: [Creating windows links on Linux?](https://serverfault.com/questions/308594/creating-windows-links-on-linux)

Unfortunately provided link to file format documentation is dead but you can use https://ithreats.files.wordpress.com/2009/05/lnk_the_windows_shortcut_file_format.pdf instead of it. And try to compile (or use bash version) mslink